# Magento2 : add custom module to config.php is not working

Tags: module, magento2

I am creating front-end module i.e. (abc/helloworld) and adding module in `app/etc/config.php`

Screenshot :

[image: Config.php image]

after that run following command in terminal

```
  bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

but the custom module  is not showing in module listing.

Screenshot :

[image]

Here is the module.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <module name="Abc_HelloWorld" setup_version="2.0.0">
   </module>
 </config>
```

& registrarion.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Abc_Helloworld',
   __DIR__
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need have file registration.php in custom module

Comment: but when put registration.php it gives error `There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.`

Comment: show your module.xml and registration.php.

Comment: What are you using magento 2 version ?

Comment: @SohelRana : I have added module.xml

Comment: @PaW : its magento 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Since the official release of Magento 2.0.0, you can't manually declare a module in `config.php`. Instead, add a file named `registration.php` in your module folder:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'[Vendor Name]_[Module Name]',
__DIR__);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

**module.xml** and location

```
app/code/Abc/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Abc_HelloWorld" setup_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**composer.json** and location

```
app/code/Abc/HelloWorld/composer.json
```

```
{
    "name": "abc/module-helloworld",
    "description": "helloworld",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Abc\\HelloWorld\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**registration.php** and location

```
app/code/Abc/HelloWorld/registration.php
```

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Abc_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

Clear magento cache, **(delete var/di if exist)** and run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**NB: var folder permission should be 777**

Comment: I have made changes according to your post. Issue still remains same.

Comment: can you create new one according to my post?

Comment: be careful for naming convention.

Comment: problem still remains

Comment: bad luck, it should work because it's tested code.

Comment: i have change the name of my module `HelloWorld to Helloworld` and its run

Comment: HelloWorld has 2 capital latter H & W. So folder name should be 'HelloWorld' not 'Helloworld'. So when you create any module takecare about strict name convention.